# iptables - how to set class by ip address instead of port?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

i want to set a specific class to any packets that come from a specific computer in my network using --set-class, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: This is better to be asked on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the iprange built-in iptables module that supports ip-ranges for src and dst addresses.

thanks.